# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - event2/event-config.h file not found

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, flipper

I have a cleanly installed Mac `10.15.7`, with freshly installed xCode (`12.4`) on in it. I installed `react-native` following the official instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). I created a new project and tried to build it (from Xcode), but ended up with this error:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - event2/event-config.h file not found

[image: Error Message]

It appears to have something to do with `Flipper`. I have absolutely no clue how to fix this, as I am not familiar with `CPP` development and the file/data-structure it needs...

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript when a c/c++ header file is missing?

Comment: @Andreas Because React-Native is a JS library and maybe some other JS developers encountered the same problem when writing RN apps.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's because there is a new version of Flipper and React Native might not come with the right one so best is to go in your podfile and add this `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' })` then run `pod install`

Comment: Works great. Specifically, i replaced the "use_flipper!" (which was defaulting to '0.54.0') to "use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' })"

Comment: Better get latest version using "npm info flipper" so you can put the right version on podfile
You may need to do "pod repo update"

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED:

First i tried to add `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' })` But it didnt solve my error then i commented out this like like `# use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' })` and run `pod install` it started working.

Honestly don't know how :)

Comment: Did you run `pod install` after specifying Flipper's version? If not, that's the problem. When you commented out `use_fliper...` and then ran pod install it removed the problematic version of flipper and your project was able to build.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the latest version of Flipper SDK, from here: https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/

For example: `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.78.0' })` then run `pod install` in the `ios` directory.

This fixed it for me.