# Error build react native ios use yarn ios new project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I want to build ios with xcode 12.4, ios14.4 with react native. the error like this

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testIos2-gadmwivyqenuohhdfabybpprezqk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00015310.sh
(1 failure)
```

Please someone help me, i am using intel mac os catalina and this my pod file

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'cobaIos' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'cobaIosTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end


  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

thank you i hope it can be solve because it takse 2 day and not solving anymore

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118122/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-event2-event-config-h-file-not-found

Comment: Can you please add your pod file code here.

Comment: i have adding my podfile

Comment: ok try : https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2215#issuecomment-827422023 this one

Comment: i have check and same with the github code. i have try to make a new project yarn ios again. come error like this ```PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testIos2-gadmwivyqenuohhdfabybpprezqk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00015310.sh ```

Comment: in xcode the error like this ```/bin/sh: /Users/user/Desktop/Nicholas/Mobile: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code```

Comment: The error happens if you use the wrong version of node. Try making sure you are using node 12.0. if react-native is 0.64.0

Comment: if i use node 16, i must downgrade to node 12?

Comment: also if it is m1 then issue will be resolved using this just run the nvm unalias default

Comment: my rn version 0.69.2 and node 16.16.0

Comment: zsh: command not found: nvm, i done have nvm

Comment: ok for node 16. create project with npx react-native init

Comment: i have create new project with npx react-native init, but the same error like this in xcode ```/bin/sh: /Users/user/Desktop/Nicholas/Mobile: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code``` and ```PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cobaIos2-eebuhywmpdkvangjebxmuhhcvibv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00015310.sh
(1 failure)``` in react native

Comment: please help me, i am new for develop ios device in react native

Comment: your getting this error when you run pod install ?

Comment: no, yarn ios. pod install success but only yarn ios in simulator device

Comment: Xcode -> File -> Workspace Setting -> change Build System to Legacy Build System.

Note - Its not the ideal solution.

Comment: still the same error :(

Comment: in build settings. if VALID_ARCHS was containing x86_64. After delete it.

Comment: i have the this tutorial image https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X9MM.png , but menu Valid Arch not found

Comment: Go to Target > Architectures Set Build Active Architecture Only to YES and Excluded Architectures to x86_64

Comment: in build setting menu? i can't change the setting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68581482/6654562

Comment: i have change the setting of arch, i run again and got new error ,```The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testIos-gxoxizdamvsolbfoyijjzpedgzny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testIos.app/testIos normal```

Comment: metro has started but get the error like before

Comment: Restart the Mac it can be cache issue. Clear Derive data

Comment: i have restart mac and clear derive data. this error come ```CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testIos-gxoxizdamvsolbfoyijjzpedgzny/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testIos.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testIos.build/Objects-normal/arm64/testIos_vers.o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testIos-gxoxizdamvsolbfoyijjzpedgzny/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testIos.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testIos.build/DerivedSources/testIos_vers.c normal arm64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/6654562

Comment: I suppose project is working.

Comment: i do the link arm 64 and get this error again, so confused. ```PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosCoba-bgiogopapvxlzwfmpjjsemxynwnf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00015310.sh```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of mix matched version of react native and flipper.

for react-native 63+ it should be following

`use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.58.0' })` then `run pod install`

More more clarity go through this documentation for manual setup : https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native-ios/

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin": get error like this